sql developer login failed CONNECTION_ID=nsb+4IVkQBKpwSfU4qE+wA==
Oracle SQL Developer is giving me nightmare(been trying for 6 hrs)
docker exec -it my_oracle_db sqlplus sys/12345@ORCLCDB as sysdba this command works as you can see in the screenshot

but sql developer doesn't work

error: Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=nsb+4IVkQBKpwSfU4qE+wA==)
also,
docker exec -it my_oracle_db sqlplus c##abhimanyuaryan/12345@ORCLCDB
work but it doesn't in sqldeveloper. I just removed role sysdba


SQLDeveloper running on your host?

you need port 1521 on your host to be mapped to 1521 on your container

it's running on my macos instead of docker @p3consulting

It is resolved now. Thanks
